# How to define a function that has a condition as input?

Tags: python, function

I need a function that takes a rule/condition as an input. for example given an array of integers detect all the numbers that are greater than two, and all the numbers greater than four. I know this can be achieved easily without a function, but I need this to be inside a function. The function I would like to have is like

```py
def _select(x,rule):    
    outp = rule(x)
    return outp    
    
L = np.round(np.random.normal(2,4,50),decimals=2)     
y = _select(x=L,rule=(>2))
y1 = _select(x=L,rule=(>4))
```

How should I code a function like this?

Comment: Note that `_select` is really just the old `apply` function from Python 2, which is being reintroduced as `operator.call` in Python 3.11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions are first class objects meaning you can treat them as any other variable.

```
import numpy as np

def _select(x,rule):

    outp = rule(x)
    return outp

def rule_2(val):
    return val > 2

def rule_4(val):
    return val > 4

L = np.round(np.random.normal(2,4,50),decimals=2)
 
y = _select(x=L,rule=rule_2)
print(y)
y1 = _select(x=L,rule=rule_4)
print(y1)
```

In your example, the condition you want to use can be expressed as a simple expression. The python `lambda` keyword lets you define expressions as anonymous functions in other statements and expressions. So, you could replace the explicit `def` of the functions

```
import numpy as np

def _select(x,rule):

    outp = rule(x)
    return outp

L = np.round(np.random.normal(2,4,50),decimals=2)
 
y = _select(x=L,rule=lambda val: val > 2)
print(y)
y1 = _select(x=L,rule=lambda val: val > 4)
print(y1)
```

Comment: Absolutely the only right answer to that question, +1. Anyway I would add the type hints to make it even more clear.